# Generate JWT token with ECDSA private key

Tags: java, java-8, jwt

Trying to generate  signed JWT token  with EDCSA private jkey but getting errored out

Generate public and private key using link

https://techdocs.akamai.com/iot-token-access-control/docs/generate-jwt-ecdsa-keys

```
 private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    String EC_PRIVATE_KEY_STR = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        + "MHQCAQEEIBuSmY4MFZ938j0sno1nOICb0ScfIebC1O7DXkvf6UDMoAcGBSuBBAAK\n"
        + "oUQDQgAELAWORZuUv+lpO34bVoYHv6T3Gey+GtuHFB+TH1+l0tRKfKELHcmHlDOK\n"
        + "ebiIegDVhHd6jYx2yT1nOBddjDHCVw==\n"
        + "-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    final KeyFactory keyPairGenerator = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC"); // EC is ECDSA in Java
    ECPrivateKey EC_PRIVATE_KEY = (ECPrivateKey) keyPairGenerator.generatePrivate(
        new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            Base64.decodeBase64(removeEncapsulationBoundaries(EC_PRIVATE_KEY_STR))));

    var currentDateTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    final String jwt = Jwts.builder()
        .setHeaderParam("kid", "any")
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.ES256, EC_PRIVATE_KEY)
        .compact();
    return jwt;
  }
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch: (supported:     00, parsed:     01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` requires a key in PKCS8 format (and specifically PKCS8-clear); that's why the name says PKCS8. **That's not a PKCS8-format key** so it fails.

To read the key:

If you're generating the key with OpenSSL, as per the website you link (though on the previous page), the easiest way is to convert with OpenSSL:

```
$ cat ecprivate-sec1
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIBuSmY4MFZ938j0sno1nOICb0ScfIebC1O7DXkvf6UDMoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAELAWORZuUv+lpO34bVoYHv6T3Gey+GtuHFB+TH1+l0tRKfKELHcmHlDOK
ebiIegDVhHd6jYx2yT1nOBddjDHCVw==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
$ openssl pkey <ecprivate-sec1 >ecprivate-pkcs8
$ cat ecprivate-pkcs8
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGEAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAKBG0wawIBAQQgG5KZjgwVn3fyPSyejWc4
gJvRJx8h5sLU7sNeS9/pQMyhRANCAAQsBY5Fm5S/6Wk7fhtWhge/pPcZ7L4a24cU
H5MfX6XS1Ep8oQsdyYeUM4p5uIh6ANWEd3qNjHbJPWc4F12MMcJX
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If you have an ancient (0.9.x) version of OpenSSL, instead do `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt`.

That value, with the BEGIN/END lines removed and de-base64'ed, will be accepted by Java.

Or OpenSSL can generate this format directly; instead of `ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -noout ...` use:

```bash
openssl genpkey -algorithm ec -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:secp256k1 >ecprivate-pkcs8
# but see below
```

(Also you can use *either* `ec -pubout` or `pkey -pubout` to get the public key, and the format OpenSSL uses for public key *is*, after de-PEM-ing, the 'X.509' format Java wants.)

Alternatively, if BouncyCastle is available *including* bcpkix, *that* can handle the 'traditional' SEC1/rfc5915 format *in PEM* directly. With your above EC_PRIVATE_KEY_STR value just do:

```
PrivateKey privkey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getKeyPair (
    (PEMKeyPair) new PEMParser(new StringReader(EC_PRIVATE_KEY_STR)).readObject() 
    ).getPrivate();
```

(you can declare, and cast to, `ECPrivateKey` if you want but don't need to).

**But that's still wrong.**

I don't if anyone did quality control on that website, but [JWS ES256 uses ECDSA with P-256](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.1), the curve also known as secp256r1 and prime256v1, **NOT secp256k1** which is an entirely different and wrong curve. Instead when generating with OpenSSL you should specify either `P-256` or `prime256v1`.

The example they give using command-line `openssl` to sign doesn't catch this, because OpenSSL is a general purpose tool used for many things not just JOSE/JWS, and for some (other) things secp256k1 is correct. More surprising to me, jjwt -- at least the slightly old version I have -- also doesn't catch this. Nevertheless the result does not comply to the standard and will not be reliably accepted by other systems.

Comment: thanks i did found the solution but yes as u said  key needs to be changed to PKCS8 as well for version mismatch issues. thanks for taking your time and replying . Accepting your reply as answer . repo for the site you shared - https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt